# Setting up own NIC

Tags: dns-hosting, tld

Since ICANN approved .whatever domains, i would like to get my own .something domain and have people look up free domains on my .something tld and register .something with me. What would i need to achieve this and is there a script that's out there that i can install on my server? Is there a setup that i need to have to make this work.

Not sure if this is the right place to post this (StackOverFlow? ServerFault? SuperUser? WebApps?)

Comment: Since you're not concerned about finances and you're not going to hire a consultant this reeks of homework.

Comment: As for which site to ask such a question on: None of the above.

Answer (score 5):

You should familiarise yourself with the application process by reviewing the [gTLD Applicant Handbook](http://www.icann.org/en/topics/new-gtlds/dag-en.htm). The first thing you need to achieve this is a minimum $185,000 US which is the gTLD Evaluation fee and thereafter $25,000 US annual fee.

If you decide to progress then you would probably be much better off buying the services of a consultant.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is an easy task to get approved. This needs an application fee of $185,000, and the annual fee of $25,000. I doubt if it is worth of trying for individuals or small companies.

Comment: Not worried about the finances. Really need to know how the infrastructure will be setup. What servers i would need, software?

Comment: homework by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

Beyond the fees which have been mentioned already you have to be able to show that you are able to setup a redundant DNS infrastructure to host the DNS for the gTLD.

Comment: How to setup that DNS infrastructure is what i need to know. Hardware, software?

Comment: Hardware wise, I believe that you'll need several sites, each of which hosts multiple DNS servers.  You need to have multiple servers at each site with DNS running on each one so that DNS is redundant.  You'll need some good sized servers as you'll need to support millions of hits an hour if not more.  Plus the networking equipment, firewalls, loads of bandwidth, etc.  For the software a *nix OS and bind will probably be the most popular choice. There's not going to be a lot of info out there, only a couple of companies run DNS servers.